# Matlab error: dataread Second input must be a filename or string to parse

Tags: matlab

I am trying to spilt string in editbox using following code

```
 text=get(handles.edit1, 'string'); %get editbox text

  [A]=strread(text,'%s','delimiter',' ');
```

But it is giving error as

> Error using ==> dataread
>   Second input must be a filename or string to parse.
>
> Error in ==> strread at 51
>       [varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('string',varargin{:});

If I pass string directly to strread
 `[A]=strread('Hello folks','%s','delimiter',' ');`
Then it is working fine.

Why it is not working with editbox. Please help me.

Comment: What is the size/type of `text`?

Comment: Your `get` do not work as you expect. Write:
`get` as a second line of your code to print the contents.   
Are you sure that your edit is named as `edit1`?

Comment: Oh, write `text` to print it

Comment: @nkjt type is string. and size of text is dependent on user input

Comment: @John_West edit is named as edit1. I tried to print text and it gives output. But the problem arises when strread is performed.

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning something unexpected, e.g. if you put a stop if error in, you get a string of the size you expect, not a cell array or empty return or something?

Comment: @nkjt input =

   Empty string: 1-by-0


??? Error using ==> dataread
Second input must be a filename or string to parse.

Comment: @nkjt I changed the delimiter to , and it it is working fine. The problem is with ' ' (space).

Comment: I can't replicate; `strread` works fine with a space delimiter for me. If you're getting "Empty string: 1-by-0" then something's going wrong with the bit where you fetch the info from the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have `Matlab`, but I have `GNU octave`, which usually has analogous functionality.

*Figure and edit creation code [from link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154660).*

```
% Create the figure
mFigure = figure('Name', 'myplot', 'Tag', 'main')

% Create a uicontrol of type "text"
mTextBox = uicontrol('style','text','Tag','edit1')
set(mTextBox,'String','Hello World')

handles = guihandles(mFigure);

% the code from OP goes here
text=get(handles.edit1, 'string'); %get editbox text

[A]=strread(text,'%s','delimiter',' ');
A
```

The output is:

```
A = 
{
  [1,1] = Hello
  [2,1] = World
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine with delimiter other than ' ' (space)